# Prevent Magento from editing content code?

Tags: jquery, html, magento, editing

I'm still fairly new to the magento CMS.  I'm in the process of building some product pages for the company I'm working for, and when I add several lines of html code for a jquery plugin I installed magento starts editing them.  After a few save and refreshes Magento then periodically deems some of my code as irrelevant and removes it on its own and then my page goes to hell.  Is there a setting in the admin panel that can stop it from doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I see you've come acquainted with the dreaded Magento WYSIWYG editor.

The simplest approach to your issue is to disable the WYSIWYG editor by default.

Go to `System > Configuration > Content Management`.  Under `WYSIWYG Options`, Change `Enable WYSIWYG Editor` to `Disabled By Default`.

This will prevent the WYSIWG editor from loading by default when you're editing CMS content.  Simply write your code in the content textareas and don't activate the WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 0):

Related tip:

In case you just hit EDIT and the WYSIWYG has lost all of your syntatical html!

Using chrome inspector you can inspect the text field and see the **original** piece of data. Copy it and paste it in, make your changes and save this tip for another day